# Does MapServer's .map file support more than one set of S3 credentials using VSIS3?

Tags: mapserver

Is it possible to use more than one set of S3 credentials on a .map file, when using VSIS3?
Say just for visualization that .vrt files are stored on an AWS S3 bucket, while the images where .vrt reaches are stored on Google Cloud S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS credentials can only be set in the `MAP` section of a Mapfile as `CONFIG` options - which then set the GDAL environment variables as documented at https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html#vsis3-aws-s3-files

```
MAP
    NAME "Test"
    CONFIG "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" "XXXXX"
    CONFIG "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" "XXXXX"
    CONFIG "AWS_S3_ENDPOINT" "s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Update based on the https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html link from @Turo:

For different credentials for different buckets, the following approach can be used.

- Set the GDAL_CONFIG_FILE environment variable in the MapServer CONFIG file:

```
CONFIG
    ENV
        GDAL_CONFIG_FILE "/etc/mapserver/mapfiles/gdal.conf"
    END
END
```

In the `gdal.conf` set credentials for different paths used:

```
[credentials]

# need to restart MapServer if these values change

[.sentinel-cogs]
path=/vsis3/sentinel-cogs
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX
AWS_REQUEST_PAYER=requester
# defaults
#AWS_S3_ENDPOINT=s3.amazonaws.com
#AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1

[.sentinel-cogs2]
path=/vsis3/sentinel-cogs2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXX
AWS_REQUEST_PAYER=requester
```

Now a Mapfile will use different credentials based on the `LAYER` `DATA` clause:

```
LAYER
    # will use sentinel-cogs settings
    DATA "/vsis3/sentinel-cogs/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/43/R/FL/2022/2/S2A_43RFL_20220213_0_L2A/B01.tif"

...

LAYER
    # will use sentinel-cogs2 settings
    DATA "/vsis3/sentinel-cogs2/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/43/R/FL/2022/2/S2A_43RFL_20220213_0_L2A/B01.tif"
```

Comment: I see an option of a config file to be used as well in GDAL https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html and there is specifically an example with multiple S3 paths. Any chances this GDAL setting could be respected by mapserver as well? did not have a chance to check this yet.

Comment: @Turo - good find. In theory creating the GDAL config file and setting GDAL_CONFIG_FILE in a MAP file or MapServer CONFIG file should work.

Comment: @Turo - I can confirm the GDAL config file works with MapServer - answer updated.

Comment: thank you for your insight and check.